# Does a Meson hit earth or not hit earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, elementary-particles

I am told a $\mu$ meson with an average lifespan of $2 \times 10^{-6}$ is created in the upper atmosphere at an altitude of $6000m$. When it is created, it has a velocity of $0.998c$ in a direction towards the Earth.

1. What is the average distance that it will travel before decaying, as determined by an observer on earth
2. Consider an observer at rest with respect to the $\mu$ meson. What is the distance he/she measures from the point of creation of the $\mu$ meson to the earth?

The question I have is, is the particle lifespan given measured in the (a) laboratory frame or in the (b) eigentime of the particle? How are these values usually quoted in physics?

If I interpret it as case (a), the answer for $1$ is $9472\ m$. If I interpret it as case (b) the answer for $1$ is $598\ m$. Are my values and understanding correct? If not, where did I go wrong? My answer for $2$ is $379.29\ m$

Comment: Please note that [check my work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) questions are considered to be off-topic here, but Emilio has answered your core conceptual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question I have is, is the particle lifespan given measured in the (a) laboratory frame or in the (b) eigentime of the particle? How are these values usually quoted in physics?

Particle lifetimes are always given in the rest frame of the particle.

As you've seen in your course, this lifetime will look different in other frames of reference, and the specific value of the observed lifetime will depend on the relative velocity between the particle and the frame. As such, it makes no sense to quote values in other frames of reference, as there is an infinity of such values.

Comment: Annoyingly, the Wikipedia articles on exponential decay and half-life do not explicitly mention that mean lifetimes and half-lives are given wirh respect to the rest frame.